# Kurento one2one sample runs smoothly on local but lags heavily on server

Tags: server, webrtc, kurento

I installed Kurento 6.0 one2one video call sample on my local machine and tested in local network. Chat worked smoothly. After that I put it on my dedicated server and tried it over internet. It starts to lag and freeze 10 or 15 seconds after the start of call. The server has 16mbits download speed and 10 mbits upload speed. It seems enough for one conference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what's your connection speed? Please check also the CPU load, as if you've chosen a very small instance, or using a computer vision filter, you might find that it's eating up all your resources.

---

EDIT 1

It looks like the link quality of your client is not very good, and the lagging is not in the server, but in the client.

Comment: Kurento media server uses %2 - %3 of the CPU. Clients' connection speeds are 44mbps download and 2mbps upload. I didn't edit the sample so there is no filter.

Comment: We tried it from different internet connections and it worked much better. Does it happen because Kurento scales quality according to connection speed?

Comment: Not Kurento, but WebRTC. Each peer sends information about its link, and the other peer adapts to the announced available bandwidth.

Comment: Is there any way to override it by Kurento?

Comment: Changed FPS to 5 in kurento-utils.js but it ignores it and still tries to adapt i think.

Comment: Which version of the library are you using? There was a bug in constraints in a recent version. You'll need the latest development version.

Comment: I installed the latest version from github a few days ago. Kurento media server version is 6.2.0. By the way, framerate does not work but i changed width of the video and it's smoother now.

Comment: Get the latest version of that library, as we had a bug in the constraints that might be affecting you. Also, keep in mind that the FPS is most likely a best-effort on the client part, and that some framerates/dimensions combinations might not work with your webcam. Check different clients just in case.